# Sheets Scripting executions suddenly became much slower and all function duration times have increased

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, execution-time

I have a Google Sheets Script (several actually) that always have performed well.. Execution in just a few seconds. Now each one takes minutes!

I run these scripts from picture buttons in one of the tabs, about 2 times each month because they are pay/billing related.

The last time I ran it (about 2 weeks ago,) I noticed it was terribly slow and so I decided to go away from the computer and come back later.  When I returned the script had completed.

Thinking it was a fluke, because the script has not changed, I figured there was an internet blip or something. So I tried the script again, and it ran in just a few seconds.

Now, 2 weeks later and I go to run the script, and EVERY script is taking an order of magnitude longer, if not more.

I have looked at the Execution Transcripts and find no errors but only LONG periods of time.  Keep in mind that each sheet where I get range only has 39 rows!

I have checked the Chrome Browser version is up to date.

I have refreshed and rebooted.

Code:

```
function grabTotals() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),
      temp = ss.getSheetByName('TEMPLATE'),
      j = 0, // set for rows to populate amounts
      sumTotal = 0, //adding up for TOTAL on report
      all = ss.getSheetByName('BILLING_DASHBOARD'),
      sheets = ss.getSheets(),
      vals = all.getRange('d6:j').getValues();  // (WAS d5) Must set row before what is needed or it misses last counted down item
  ss.getSheetByName("SummaryTotals").activate().getRange("B2:C100").clearContent();

  for (var i = vals.length-1; i > 0; i--) {
    var name = vals[i][6]; //make array of the names from column
    if (name !='') {
      //Set up here an IF for checking vals[i][1] or [0] for the TRUE checkmark
      var isOn = vals[i][0]; // check for checkbox
      if (isOn) {
        var theActiveSheet = ss.getSheetByName(name);
        if (theActiveSheet !=null) {

          Logger.log(theActiveSheet &"---"& theActiveSheet.getName());

          var theAmounts = theActiveSheet.getRange("I13").getValues(); //Get the Total for check on named sheet

          if( theAmounts > 0) {//Zeros are not shown on summary or totaled
              ss.getSheetByName("SummaryTotals").getRange(3+j, 3).setValue(theAmounts); //Write amount from named sheet to the Summary sheet
              ss.getSheetByName("SummaryTotals").getRange(3+j, 2).setValue(vals[i][1]); //Write the NAME on the sheet to the Summary sheet

              Logger.log(theActiveSheet &"|||"& theActiveSheet.getName() &"|||"& theAmounts & "|||"& vals[i][1]);

              ss.getSheetByName("SummaryTotals").insertRows(4+j, 1);  //insert a row (May not be necessary)
              sumTotal = parseFloat(sumTotal) + parseFloat(theAmounts); //Keep a running balance for the Total on the Summary Sheet... done below
              j++;
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  multiSortColumns(); // UNCOMMENT for sorting.
  ss.getSheetByName("SummaryTotals").getRange(4+j, 2).setValue("Total");
  ss.getSheetByName("SummaryTotals").getRange(4+j, 3).setValue(sumTotal);
}
```

Execution Transcript

```
[19-05-15 15:23:11:903 PDT] Starting execution
[19-05-15 15:23:11:917 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:12:194 PDT] Sheet.protect() [0.276 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:22:627 PDT] Protection.setDescription([Sample protected sheet]) [10.432 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:22:628 PDT] Session.getEffectiveUser() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:22:629 PDT] User.getEmail() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:32:743 PDT] Protection.addEditor([jgarner@usmpllc.com]) [10.114 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:32:744 PDT] Protection.getEditors() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:43:122 PDT] Protection.removeEditors([[jgarner@usmpllc.com]]) [10.378 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:43:123 PDT] Protection.canDomainEdit() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:43:124 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:43:125 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([TEMPLATE]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:43:125 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([BILLING_DASHBOARD]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:43:131 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheets() [0.006 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:43:132 PDT] Sheet.getRange([d6:j]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:53:561 PDT] Range.getValues() [10.428 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:53:562 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:53:562 PDT] Sheet.activate() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:53:563 PDT] Sheet.getRange([B2:C100]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:53:564 PDT] Range.clearContent() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:53:564 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([jgaul]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:53:564 PDT] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:53:565 PDT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:23:53:566 PDT] Sheet.getRange([I13]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:130 PDT] Range.getValues() [20.564 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:131 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:132 PDT] Sheet.getRange([3, 3]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:133 PDT] Range.setValue([[[4200.0]]]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:133 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:134 PDT] Sheet.getRange([3, 2]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:134 PDT] Range.setValue([Jay Gaul]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:134 PDT] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:135 PDT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:14:135 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:24:375 PDT] Sheet.insertRows([4, 1]) [10.239 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:24:479 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([jgarner]) [0.103 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:24:480 PDT] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:24:480 PDT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:24:481 PDT] Sheet.getRange([I13]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:489 PDT] Range.getValues() [10.007 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:489 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:490 PDT] Sheet.getRange([4, 3]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:490 PDT] Range.setValue([[[3850.0]]]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:491 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:491 PDT] Sheet.getRange([4, 2]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:492 PDT] Range.setValue([Jim Garner]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:505 PDT] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:506 PDT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:34:507 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:44:758 PDT] Sheet.insertRows([5, 1]) [10.25 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:44:862 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([gimes]) [0.103 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:44:862 PDT] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:44:863 PDT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:44:863 PDT] Sheet.getRange([I13]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:868 PDT] Range.getValues() [10.004 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:869 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:869 PDT] Sheet.getRange([5, 3]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:870 PDT] Range.setValue([[[3456.6]]]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:870 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:870 PDT] Sheet.getRange([5, 2]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:871 PDT] Range.setValue([Grant Imes]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:871 PDT] Sheet.getName() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:872 PDT] Logger.log([0.0, []]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:24:54:872 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:595 PDT] Sheet.insertRows([6, 1]) [10.722 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:596 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:696 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0.099 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:697 PDT] Sheet.getRange([B3:C]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:697 PDT] Range.sort([[{column=2.0, ascending=true}]]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:801 PDT] Spreadsheet.toast([Sort complete.]) [0.103 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:802 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:803 PDT] Sheet.getRange([7, 2]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:803 PDT] Range.setValue([Total]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:804 PDT] Spreadsheet.getSheetByName([SummaryTotals]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:804 PDT] Sheet.getRange([7, 3]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:05:805 PDT] Range.setValue([11506.6]) [0 seconds]
[19-05-15 15:25:15:777 PDT] Execution succeeded [82.682 seconds total runtime]
```

I am not a good scripter, but I do make things work pretty well usually!
This however is beyond me... It is like everything broke at once, leaving me to wonder if there was a drastic change from Google that I didn't know about.
**Did I pay my GSuite bill?!

Please help me locate the problem and work to eliminate it before next billing cycle!

No errors. Just Very long execution which NEVER was happening before.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the guide on [How to Ask Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also looking up a style guide for Javascript and being careful with your formatting; it will help you find your mistakes on your own, and get you better answers when you can't. 

As the transcript shows, the main issue is that reading from the sheet is taking a long time. There's no obvious cause in your code from what I can see, but you can [use batch operations](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) to improve performance

Comment: For a question like this, it's important to provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex), which should ideally include the full code of the script as well as the Spreadsheet, as the length of time to fetch values from it will vary greatly by its content, especially in this case, as logic in your script depends on the content of the sheet.

Comment: Firstly, Thank you very much for taking the time to format properly.  I will try to learn more and do better.
Next: I did comment that there are only 30+ rows to the sheets where info is read. Is this sufficient?  If not, I will have to do some sort of security to it, since it has names and financial information.
Although the numbers change each period, nothing else does! No one touches these sheets but me, and THAT is programmatic really, as I do an import-range from other spreadsheets.

I think you can see the dates and that it goes fast then slow.
There was NO content change for that.

Comment: I COULD take a shot at rebuilding those scripts with batch operations, but before I spend a lot of time (for me) I think I need to understand WHY this has just started happening.  It does seem as though this issue is outside of my code or changes that I make.

Please do comment back on that position?  I don't want to go down that road if the code is sound enough to stick with and I simply need to have a Google Support call.
Thank you!